# Find polynomials $f (x)$, $g(x)$, and $h(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

In an elementary Algebra book (101 problems in Algebra) there was a question I solved but when  I looked at the solutions I didn't get it. it says find Polynomials $f(x)$, $g(x)$, $h(x)$ such that for all $x$:

[image]

I appreciate if you explain where did $F(X)$ come from .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$F(x)$ is just the original piecewise linear function you are given. The expression for $F(x)$ comes from adjusting the middle part of the original function so that it becomes equal to $F$ throughout its range.

So we start with $3x+2$. When $x\lt -1$ we need this to become $-1$, and $-1-(3x+2)=-3x-3$. If $x\ge -1$ we want to leave the function unchanged, by adding zero. This is achieved by adding $\max (-3x-3,0)$ to the original function.

Note that you might have needed the min function instead, or to subtract rather than add, but these functions work because the function is continuous at $x=-1$.

The term with $\max (5x,0)$ arises by considering $x\gt 0$ in the same way. I'll leave that for you to work out.

Comment: that was quick , tnx , I get it now :)